# Logic of bash function

Tags: bash

I have to fix a bash start/stop script but I am not very knowledgeable about bash.

The script starts like this

```
name='basename $0'
pid_file="/home/$name.pid"
dir="/home/somedir"
user="someuser"
cmd="somecmd"

get_pid() {
  cat "$pid_file"
}

is_running() {
  [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
   start)
   if is_running; then
      echo "Already started"
   else
      echo "Starting $name"
      cd $dir
      sudo -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$dtderr_log" &
      echo $! > "$pid_file"
      if ! is_running; then
          echo "Unable to start, see $stdout_log" 2>> "$stderr_log" &
          exit 1
      fi
   fi
```

How does is_running() work? It seems it  returns a boolean but I dont understand the logic.
The sudo command starts the process correctly but it always reports that it has been unable to start because is_running is false

Comment: See http://explainshell.com/.

Comment: That is also a slightly poor `is_running` test since it doesn't care *what* process is running with that pid (it could be anything).

Comment: @ Etan Reisner I think indeed the issue is with get_pid. What happens is the sudo command runs a shell script that creates two pids. How would I change the is_running to accomodate that?

Comment: @John Kugelman Thanks for the link

Comment: two pids: if you start a single (sudo) command, you get a single PID. This (sudo) command may start other processes in its context, but these PIDs are not visible to the parent. You have to use ps to look for these PIDs.

Answer (score 2):

As John Kugelman pointed out you can get some hints to the logic from his link, although not everything. The logic in the function is_running is simple, first it checks if the file with the process id (pid) exists:

```
[ -f "$pid_file" ]
```

this will return 0 if it does exist and 1 if it does not. The && then checks if the previous command was successful (returned 0) and executes the part after && if and only if the previous command returned 0. The next command:

```
ps 'get_pid'
```

lists the processes running with the pid from the function get_pid (which is the text in the file). This commands evaluates to 0 if a process with the provided pid is running and 1 if there is none. The last part of the function:

```
 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

redirects the output from the command ps 'get_pid' to null and any errors to the terminal (standard output).

In summary the is_running will return 0 (as in true) if the file where a pid is stored, and the pid in this file is a currently running process as seen by ps.

Comment: `ps <pid>` does not always work (works on cent os linux, but not in cygwin, ...)

Answer (score 2):

In fact you would like to know three things: 1. if a given PID is running, 2. if its your process and 3. if it is the correct program. Please use `-s` to have a nonempty file.

```
is_running() {
  [ -s "$pid_file" ] && kill -0 $(< $pid_file)
}
```

kill -0 checks, if a process is running AND if it is YOUR process.

```
$ kill -0 $$                 # checking for the current bash - this should always work
$ kill -0 12345              # this process does not exist
bash: kill: (12345) - No such process
$
```

Another option would be pgrep, this would cover all three things. Please use `-s` to have a nonempty file.

```
is_running() {
  [ -s "$pid_file" ] && pgrep -U "$user" -fl "$cmd" -P $(< $pid_file)
}
```

If you start a new process, it would be best to use a wrapper like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > pidfile
exec process
```

The magic #! starts a bash, the bash knows its own PID and this PID is written to a file.
Now the exec replaces the bash process with the new one - this way, the process id (PID) stays the same!

Improved variant pidstarter.bash

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > "$1"
shift
exec "$@"
```

Now this one starts the new process and the first parameter is the pidfile.

So instead of these two lines

```
sudo -u "$user" $cmd >> "$stdout_log" 2>> "$dtderr_log" &
echo $! > "$pid_file"
```

I would use

```
sudo -u "$user" pidstarter.bash "$pid_file" $cmd &
sleep 1 # let there enough time to start bash and write pidfile
```

Comment: If I do kill -l it doesnt show 0 as a possible signal? And it sends me to the usage of kill.

Comment: Yes, it is an very old 'trick', but it is documented in the C manpage: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html: "If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; this can be used to check for the existence of a process
ID or process group ID."

Comment: `kill -0 $$` does not work? On what platform? Can't believe it!

Comment: in [ -f "$pid_file" ] && kill -0 $(< $pid_file) did you mean $(< get_pid? (pid_file is a filename not the pid). This is in ubuntu

Comment: $ echo $$ > pidfile NEWLINE
$ pid_file=pidfile NEWLINE
$ [ -f "$pid_file" ] && kill -0 $(< $pid_file) NEWLINE

Comment: The construct `$(< file)` reads a filename, just try it with: `echo hello > x; echo "file_content of '$x' is '$(< x)'"`

Comment: Tried kill -0, def not available in ubuntu. Tried pgrep it tells me pgrep: option requires an argument -- 'P'

Comment: kill -0 is a shell builtin of bash - it is always available. If the file is empty, then the -P argument is empty, which results in the error - I corrected the script.

Comment: You have to use `-s` instead of `-f` (-s FILE        True if file exists and is not empty.)